# No acabo de comprender del todo el siguiente bucle foreach en php

Tags: php

No acabo de entender el bucle del foreach me lía todo en sí. Si alguien me lo podiese explicar paso por paso de lo que hace me iría bien para el futuro. Saludos.

```html
<?php
// Suma los valores de dos arreglos.
function __sum($a, $b) {

  $c = [];  
  foreach($a as $i => $a_x) {     
    $b_x = $b[$i];    
    $c[] = $a_x + $b_x;
  }

  return $c;  
}

$a = [[2, 4, 8], [1, 3, 5]];
$b = [[1, -1, 1], [0,  1, -2]];
?>
```

Comment: Que es lo que entendes de el?

Comment: Lo de dentro del foreach no lo entiendo nada y como asigna las variables en general.

Comment: Deberían cambiar el título a **"Como funciona un foreach en PHP"**

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a la pagina de PHP

https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php

```php
foreach (expresión_array as $valor)
    sentencias
foreach (expresión_array as $clave => $valor)
    sentencias
```

La primera forma recorre el array dado por expresión_array. En cada iteración, el valor del elemento actual se asigna a $valor y el puntero interno del array avanza una posición (así en la próxima iteración se estará observando el siguiente elemento).

La segunda forma además asigna la clave del elemento actual a la variable $clave en cada iteración.

Lo que pasa en tu ejemplo es que en cada iteracion se va a asignar la posicion actual del array, empezando desde 0 hasta el indice final del array, en este caso los valores que tomaria `$i` serian 0 y 1.

Por otro lado si lo que quieres es sumar los valores de los arrays, no se esta haciendo de la mejor manera. De acuerdo a la documentacion de operadores

https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.array.php

El operador + entre dos arrays los une, y como tus arrays sus valores claves son 0, 1 y 2 para ambos siempre se va a tomar el valor de lo que este del lado izquierdo del operador.

Para sumar los valores podrias cambiarlo asi:

```php
function __sum($a, $b) {
  $c = [];  
  foreach($a as $i => $a_x) {     
    $b_x = $b[$i];
    foreach($a_x as $j => $a_y) {
        $b_y = $b[$i][$j];
        $c[$i][$j] = $a_y + $b_y;
    }
  }

  return $c;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En esta parte del código inicia un arreglo vacío para poner las uniones

```
$c =[]
```

Después inicia el foreach

```
foreach($a as $i => $a_x){
```

Donde `$a` indica el arreglo iterar, `$i` la clave del elemento y `$a_x`el valor, es decir si tuviéramos un arreglo como `$a = ['clave_1' => 'valor_1', 'clave_2' => 'valor_2']` al iterar sobre '$a', obtendríamos que en la primer iteración `$i = clave_1` y `$a_x = valor_1`, en la segunda iteración `$i = 'clave_2'` y `$a_x = 'valor_2'`.

Como no tienes keys específicas  en `$a = [[2, 4, 8], [1, 3, 5]];` se pone como key automáticamente la numeración ascendente, es decir tu arreglo sería lo mismo a eso

```
$a = [0 => [2, 4, 8], 1 => [1, 3, 5]];
```

Por lo que en la primera iteración tienes que `$i = 0` y `$a_x = [2,4,8]`

```
$b_x = $b[$i];
```

Aquí recordemos que `$i = 0` en la primera iteración, por lo que `$b_x = $b[0]`, si miramos el arreglo `$b = [ 0 => [1, -1, 1], 1 => [0,  1, -2]];`

Por lo que

```
$c[] = $a_x + $b_x;
```

es igual a `$c[] = [2, 4, 8] + [1, -1, 1]`, `$c[] =` indica que se agregara un elemento al arreglo `$c`

Aquí una parte interesante es que en php `[2, 4, 8] + [1, -1, 1]`, dará como resultado `[2,4,8]`, ¿Por qué? porque en arreglos suma todos los indices del primero arreglo con los indices del segundo que no están en el primero, en este caso los arreglos tendrían los siguientes índices `[0 => 2, 1 => 4, 2 => 8] + [0 => 1, 1 => -1, 2 => 1]`, como el primer segundo arreglo tiene todos los indices, no se agregan nuevos indices al nuevo arreglo.

Si lo que quisieras es unir ambos arreglos tendrías que usar `array_merge([2, 4, 8] ,[1, -1, 1])`, si lo que quieres es sumarlos tendrías que hacer algo como

```
foreach($a as $i => $a_x) {     
   $b_x = $b[$i];
   $ d = [];
   foreach($a_x as $ii => $aa_x {
       $d[] = $aa_x + $b_x[$ii];
   }

   $c[] = $d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás con un ejemplo más claro lo veas mejor.

```
  $personas_2 = array('Alberto',
                      'Pedro',
                      'Maria');


  foreach($personas_2 as $persona_2) {
    echo "<br /> Persona_2: ".$persona_2;
  }
```

Otro ejemplo con un array multidimensional pero con datos sencillos, así se ve mejor la mecánica.

```
<?php

$personas[0] = array(
      'nombre'=>'Pepeito',
      'apellido' => 'Grillo'
      );

$personas[1] = array(
      'nombre'=>'Juan',
      'apellido' => 'Palomo'
      );

$personas[2] = array(
      'nombre'=>'Manolo',
      'apellido' => 'Escobar'
      );



  foreach ($personas as  $clave => $persona) {
      echo "<hr/>";
      echo "Persona ".$clave."<br />";

        foreach($persona as $nombre_variable => $valor_variable) {
            echo "<br /> ".$nombre_variable.": ".$valor_variable;
        }

    }

 ?>
```

En este ejemplo al ser un array multidimensional, el primer `foreach` recorre las personas (0,1 y 2).

Cada Persona tiene un array con los datos Nombre y apellido. En cada vuelta recorre el array de cada uno y muestra su contenido.

---

Explicación según **php.net**

> El primer ejemplo recorre el array dado por **$personas_2**. En cada
>   iteración, el *valor* del elemento actual se asigna a **$persona_2** y el
>   puntero interno del array avanza una posición (así en la próxima
>   iteración se estará observando el siguiente elemento).
>
> El segundo ejemplo además asigna la clave del elemento actual a la
>   variable **$clave** en en cada iteración. En el bucle interno sucede los mismo asigna la *clave* en la variable **$nombre_variable** y el *valor* en **$valor_variable**

Fuente: https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Me parece que a esta respuesta, aunque no parece incorrecta, le falta justamente la explicacion (que es => dentro del for? que valor tiene cada una de esas variables?)

Comment: Ok. Edito y añado explicación.